# How do I fix namespace Pygame event error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python and Pygame. I saw on some of the tutorials that if you use the `from pygame import *` you can do away with using `pygame.<whatever>` when calling methods etc. However, for events, it seems to throw the error `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'get'`. How can I fix this? Here's my code:

```
from pygame import*
#import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 30

#Window initialization
init()
mixer.init() #used for sounds
screen = display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
display.set_caption("Test Game")
clock = time.Clock()

#Main game loop
running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS) #sets game frame rate

    #Handle events
    for event in event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    #Draw Here
    draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (200, 200), 40)


    #Render drawing to screen
    display.flip()

quit()
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should think twice before using star imports. On the first loop cycle of `for event in event.get():` it will re-assign `event` and on the next loop `event.get()` won't have the same meaning.

Comment: This is not a Pygame issue. It is just a very basic Python issue.

Comment: What's a better way to handle it instead of importing *?

Comment: Although it wouldn't have solved the problem here, unless the module you're using has a well defined `__all__` that you're aware of, I prefer `from pygame import event, clock`, etc.. even better IMO is the `pandas` convention of `import pandas as pd` (`import pygame as pg`).  Then you can use the much shorter `pg.event` and it's still clear where `event` is coming from.

Comment: Ok...I like the pg solution. Thanks for the tip. I think knowing where the method call/instance variable stems from is important.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `event` to `e` here:

```
for e in event.get():
    if e.type == QUIT:
```

Comment: Uggghhh...I'm so dumb. Thanks. It's making me wait 10 min to accept the answer.